# Use of struct keyword inside of struct

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
}
node;
```

In the above code there is `struct node* next` inside the `struct node`. I don't understand the meaning of it.

Comment: `struct node` is a type name. That's it.

Answer (score 5):

> In the code there is `struct node* next` inside the `struct node`. I
>   don't understand the meaning of it.

**Explanation :**

A **node** is a general term used to refer a [**self referential structure**](http://www.how2lab.com/programming/c/link-list1.php).*(click on link to know more)*

and going by definition,

> A **self referential structure** is a typical structure whose definition has one or
>   more of its member as a pointer to its own type.

Here in your code `next` is such a member of the structure `struct node` which is a pointer to it's own type therefore you see it as a pointer to itself in this manner inside of struct :

`struct node* next;`

That's the reason why **struct keyword is used inside of struct**

---

**Purpose** of using **self referential structures** :

**self referential structures** are very much helpful in building data structures such a [**linked lists**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)... and in fact the variable `next` is the very member which is useful in making links between **nodes** in a **linked list**  :)

Answer (score 0):

`struct node*` (note the `*`) is a *pointer* (`*`) to a `struct node`.  That means that one node can connect to another, via the pointer, without including the other.

This is referred to as a "linked list" structure.  I found a [Stanford University tutorial](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/) that looks like it covers the subject fairly thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, it means that next would also be of the same structure as that of node. So next will also have a field int n and another next.. Also this is dynamic so you don't have to allocate any memory before hand.. you can keep on adding as many node as you want ( you still have to assign memory to each node though -- search for how to use malloc to allocate memory to struct node )
And as it is of pointer type ( struct node* next ) it means you can store the address of your next node in to it and link nodes..
See the linked list implementation for better understanding..
I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering the title: In `C`, all non-standard types need to be prefaced with the `struct` keyword:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint8_t u8;
typedef uint32_t u32;

struct memory_arena {
    size_t size;
    u8 *base;
    size_t used;
    u32 _savePointCount;
    size_t _savePoints[8];
};

struct application_state {
#if 1
    struct memory_arena globalArena; //<---
#else
    memory_arena globalArena; //Valid C++
#endif
};
```

If it were in C-style C++, you might find this mixed and matched because it's not required.

- https://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Common_Initial_Sequence
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/structure-declarations?view=msvc-170